# Pass this.state variable through App Context

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

When I set the array data using the function getData() then try to call it in the function updateData() I get an error saying the this.state.data is undefined. Any thoughts on how I can pass a this.state variable from one function to another function in the app context provider?

Example code is below:

Any thoughts? Thank you!

```
export class AppProvider extends React.Component {
         constructor(props) {
           super(props);
           (this.state = {
             data: [],
           });
         }

         getData = async () => {
            const data = "abc"
            this.setState({ 
                data,
            });
        }

        updateData = async () => {
          console.log(this.state.data)
}

         render() {
           return (
             <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
               {this.props.children}
             </AppContext.Provider>
           );
         }
       }
```

Comment: Remove `async` from your functions since they don't contain `await` keyword.

Comment: There is nothing asyncronous in methods updateData, getData async can be removed. When you have called updateData??

Comment: I'm curious, why wrap parenthesis around this.state from the constructor?

Comment: This all makes sense. I've fixed my code to include your comments as well. Thank you!

Comment: "I'm curious, why wrap parenthesis around this.state from the constructor?" I found an example online and I worked from that. I am still trying to really understand what is going on. But with all, you guys help I am getting there. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three Things i would like to say,

1. you want to add the state variables separately so you want to do `value={{data:this.state.data}}`
2. if you plan on using these functions in another component you want to add these functions to the value prop as well
3. remove the `async` from the functions since there is no Promise to be resolved

   ```
     export class AppProvider extends React.Component {
         constructor(props) {
           super(props);
           this.state = {
             data: []
           };
         }

         getData = () => {
           const data = "abc";
           this.setState({
             data
           });
         };

         updateData = () => {
           console.log(this.state.data);
         };

         render() {
           return (
             <AppContext.Provider
               value={{
                 data: this.state.data,
                 getData: this.getData,
                 updateData: this.updateData
               }}
             >
               {this.props.children}
             </AppContext.Provider>
           );
         }
       }
   ```

checked this in a small example, CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-thunder-bmr53)